# Trying to load custom combobox with values from another combobox on mousepress event

Tags: python, combobox, event-handling, pyqt5

I am trying to control the options in comboxes with other comboboxes in pyqt5. The first is a normal combobox and control the amount of inputs of the second. The second is a custom checkable combobox and I want the users checked results to determine the options in the third combobox. When I try to load the third combobox on a mouse trigger from the event filter the program crashes.

Picture of Gui:
[image: Picture of Gui]

Picture of custom combobox:
[image: Picture of custom combobox]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

qt_creator_file = "comboboxes.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qt_creator_file)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        for i in range(6):
            self.comboBox.addItem("Combobox " + str(i))

        for i in range(6):
            self.comboBox_2.addItem("Combobox2 " + str(i))

        for i in range(6):
            self.comboBox_3.addItem("Combobox3 " + str(i))

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.UpdateCombo2)
        #self.comboBox_2.highlighted.connect(self.UpdateCombo3)
        #self.comboBox_3.highlighted.connect(self.UpdateCombo3)

        self.comboBox_3.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if target == self.comboBox_3 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print('Button Press')
            self.UpdateCombo3()

        return False


    def UpdateCombo2(self, index):
        self.comboBox_2.clear()
        for i in range(index):
            self.comboBox_2.addItem('ComboBox2' + str(index))

    def UpdateCombo3(self, index):
        self.comboBox_3.clear()
        list = self.comboBox_2.currentData()
        for i in list:
            self.comboBox_3.addItem('ComboBox3' + str(i))




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here's the CustomWidgets.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)

        # once there is a checkState set, it is rendered
    # here we assume default Unchecked
    def addItem(self, item):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).addItem(item)
        item = self.model().item(self.count()-1,0)
        #item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)

        # checking if item is checked
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:

            # making it unchecked
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

            # if not checked
        else:
            # making the item checked
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

    def itemChecked(self, index):
        item = self.model().item(i,0)
        return item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked

    def currentData(self):
        # Return the list of selected items data
        res = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                res.append(self.model().item(i).text())
        return res
```

and here's the ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>341</width>
      <height>191</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>16</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="CheckableComboBox" name="comboBox_2">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>16</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="CheckableComboBox" name="comboBox_3">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>16</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CheckableComboBox</class>
   <extends>QComboBox</extends>
   <header>CustomWidgets</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share the comboboxes.ui file

Comment: sorry just edited!

Comment: You're using an `index` argument in `UpdateCombo3()`, but in the event filter you're not sending any argument. Remove the `index` argument if you're not going to use it, otherwise you either set a default value or you correctly add that argument in the function call according to your needs.

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore but since I use the clear() the check status disappears everytime I try to reopen it. Any way to reset the checked items?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an index argument in UpdateCombo3(), but in the event filter you're not sending any argument. Remove the index argument if you're not going to use it, otherwise you either set a default value or you correctly add that argument in the function call according to your needs. – musicamante